# Cant get the grids to line up

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop, while-loop

I was making a number sliding puzzle on Python using loops, The function takes in a sequence of strings separated by commas, the grids don't line up though and I don't know why.

my program

```
import math
def get_size(data):
    count=len(data)
    sqroot=math.sqrt(count)
    n=math.ceil(sqroot)
    return n

def draw_row(data_list):
    list_to_join=[]
    for data in data_list:
        if len(data)==0:
            list_to_join.append('    ')
        elif len(data)==1:
            list_to_join.append(f'  {data} ')
        elif len(data)==2:
            list_to_join.append(f' {data} ')
    out= '│'.join(list_to_join)
    return f'│{out}│'

def draw_grid(n):
        top='┌'+'───┬'*(n-1)+'───┐'
        number=n
        print(top)
        while number>0:
                if number!=1:
                        print('│'+' x │'*n)
                        print("├" + "───┼" * (n - 1) + "───┤")
                elif number==1:
                        print('│'+' x │'*n)
                        
                number=number-1
                
        bottom='└'+'───┴'*(n-1)+'───┘'
        print(bottom)#├

def milestone_1(tiles):
    grid_tiles=tiles.split(',')
    grid_size=get_size(grid_tiles)
    print('┌───'+'┬───'*(grid_size-1)+'┐')

    for number in range(grid_size):
        row = grid_tiles[number*grid_size:(number+1)*grid_size]
        row_string= ''
        
        for tile in row:
            if tile=='':
                tile+='  '
                row_string+='│{}'.format(tile)
            elif len(tile)==1:
                tile+=' '
                row_string+='│ {}'.format(tile)
            else:
                tile+=' '
                row_string+='│{}'.format(tile)
        print(row_string + '│')

        if number< grid_size-1:
            print('├───' + '┼───'*(grid_size-1) + '┤')
    
    print('└───'+'┴───'*(grid_size-1)+'┘')
milestone_1("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,,12,13,14,11,15")
```

I have been at this all day, still no luck someone help, please.
[The output I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuHtu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a small part. For all your components you would add 'spacing' to separate the grid you are drawing. for integes of length 1 its 2 spaces. and for integers of length 2 its 3 space. However for your blank location, you define it as '' which is a null space. So you needed to actually add 4 spaces instead of the 3 you have defined.

```
import math
def get_size(data):
    count=len(data)
    sqroot=math.sqrt(count)
    n=math.ceil(sqroot)
    return n

def draw_row(data_list):
    list_to_join=[]
    for data in data_list:
        if len(data)==0:
            list_to_join.append('    ')
        elif len(data)==1:
            list_to_join.append(f'  {data} ')
        elif len(data)==2:
            list_to_join.append(f' {data} ')
    out= '│'.join(list_to_join)
    return f'│{out}│'

def draw_grid(n):
        top='┌'+'───┬'*(n-1)+'───┐'
        number=n
        print(top)
        while number>0:
                if number!=1:
                        print('│'+' x │'*n)
                        print("├" + "───┼" * (n - 1) + "───┤")
                elif number==1:
                        print('│'+' x │'*n)
                        
                number=number-1
                
        bottom='└'+'───┴'*(n-1)+'───┘'
        print(bottom)#├

def milestone_1(tiles):
    grid_tiles=tiles.split(',')
    grid_size=get_size(grid_tiles)
    print('┌───'+'┬───'*(grid_size-1)+'┐')

    for number in range(grid_size):
        row = grid_tiles[number*grid_size:(number+1)*grid_size]
        row_string= ''
        
        for tile in row:
            if tile=='':
                tile+='   ' #Add an additional space
                row_string+='│{}'.format(tile)
            elif len(tile)==1:
                tile+=' '
                row_string+='│ {}'.format(tile)
            else:
                tile+=' '
                row_string+='│{}'.format(tile)
        print(row_string + '│')

        if number< grid_size-1:
            print('├───' + '┼───'*(grid_size-1) + '┤')
    
    print('└───'+'┴───'*(grid_size-1)+'┘')
milestone_1("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,,12,13,14,11,15")
```

Comment: That would be a little more difficult.  Essentially, your grid is drawn with  a block of 5 units. I.e: "abcde" would fill your block. Given unit of size 1, there is a clear center but it fails for size 2. Perhaps extending it to a length of 6 and replacing your single digits with '01','02' for example would be a quick solution. But is it really necessary?